# Grepl values between comma and append as new column in R

Tags: r, grepl

I have the following dataframe:

```
df=read.table(text="A     
hwqnewqn,ENS.1kmsdf,jmewhqjwjenj
jjqweq3w,eqwejnqwe,ENS.gkhkgfdlsl.jkmwejre
ENSAAAAAAAAAAAA,bbbbbbbb,cccccccc", header=TRUE)
```

Let's say I need a new column B with only the string between commas that somehow match ENS

So end result should be:

```
df=read.table(text="B     
ENS.1kmsdf
ENS.gkhkgfdlsl.jkmwejre
ENSAAAAAAAAAAAA", header=TRUE)
```

Is there any approach for that?

Comment: Since it looks like it's CSV, wouldn't it be easier to parse it as such the first time? It looks as if you're discarding the `A` anyway, so `read.table(text="A\n...", header=FALSE, skip=1, sep=",")` returns the data in columns, and you can adjust the names as you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gsub`:

```
df$B <- gsub(".*(ENS[^,]*).*", "\\1", df$A)

#                                            A                       B
# 1           hwqnewqn,ENS.1kmsdf,jmewhqjwjenj              ENS.1kmsdf
# 2 jjqweq3w,eqwejnqwe,ENS.gkhkgfdlsl.jkmwejre ENS.gkhkgfdlsl.jkmwejre
# 3          ENSAAAAAAAAAAAA,bbbbbbbb,cccccccc         ENSAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you could use `vapply` with `strsplit` to test for "ENS" using `grepl`:

```
df$B <- vapply(strsplit(df$A, ","), \(x) x[grepl("ENS", x)], as.character(1L))

#                                            A                       B
# 1           hwqnewqn,ENS.1kmsdf,jmewhqjwjenj              ENS.1kmsdf
# 2 jjqweq3w,eqwejnqwe,ENS.gkhkgfdlsl.jkmwejre ENS.gkhkgfdlsl.jkmwejre
# 3          ENSAAAAAAAAAAAA,bbbbbbbb,cccccccc         ENSAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks like CSV, so assuming you are reading it in from a file, you can skip the first line (with the lone `A`) and grab the rest:

```r
read.table(text="A     
hwqnewqn,ENS.1kmsdf,jmewhqjwjenj
jjqweq3w,eqwejnqwe,ENS.gkhkgfdlsl.jkmwejre
ENSAAAAAAAAAAAA,bbbbbbbb,cccccccc", header=FALSE, sep=",", skip=1)[,2,drop=FALSE] |>
  setNames("B")
#            B
# 1 ENS.1kmsdf
# 2  eqwejnqwe
# 3   bbbbbbbb
```

Or, if you've already read it in, you can use use `read.csv` to parse the remaining text:

```r
read.csv(text = paste(df$A, collapse="\n"), header = FALSE)[,2,drop=FALSE] |>
  setNames("B")
#            B
# 1 ENS.1kmsdf
# 2  eqwejnqwe
# 3   bbbbbbbb
```

One reason that it might be better to use `read.csv` or the like is if there are quoted fields where doing a simpler string-split or regex might not split the text correctly.